# Separation space between tableofcontents items in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, table-of-contents, etoolbox, patching

In `beamer`, I guess, the separation space between the items from `tableofcontents` is stretchable:

[image]

Can you set it to a fixed value? e.g. to equal the value used in the `itemize` environment.

**Partial answer:**

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \linespread{1.4}
   \tableofcontents
\end{minipage}
```

Could someone patch this command with `etoolbox` and make it happen whenever typing only `\tableofcontents`? Thanks!

Here is a `MWE` (with `default` theme):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{Whatever Title Works}
\author{Remus M. Prunescu$^1$}
\institute{\tiny$^{1}$ Automation and Control Group, Department of Electrical Engineering, Technical University of Denmark (DTU)}

\begin{document}
\frame{
    \maketitle
}


\frame{
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
       \linespread{1.4}
       \tableofcontents
    \end{minipage}
}

\section{Introduction}
\frame{
    \frametitle{Random}
    \lipsum[1]
}

\section{Project Description}
\frame{
    \frametitle{Random}
    \lipsum[2]
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15265/adjusting-vertical-space-between-toc-entries-using-beamer?rq=1

Comment: @samcarter Thanks! The minipage approach works but I would like it embedded into \tableofcontents (maybe by patching the command using etoolbox). Do you know how to do that?

Comment: sorry, I think this is beyond my ability. Some experts anywhere around here?

Comment: @percusse I added a MWE with default theme - looks different than the screenshot but the effect is still there.

Comment: The command that needs patching is not `\tableofcontents`, but `\beamer@sectionintoc`; see my answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

And here's the proper way to do it in `beamer`: the inner command `\beamer@sectionintoc` (defined in `beamerbasetoc.sty`) inserts `\vfill` after each section entry in the ToC; patch the command to suppress `\vfill` and use a vertical skip of `\itemsep` (the separation between items in a list) or any other length that suits your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}
  {\vfill}
  {\vskip\itemsep}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother  

\title{Whatever Title Works}
\author{Remus M. Prunescu$^1$}
\institute{\tiny$^{1}$ Automation and Control Group, Department of Electrical Engineering, Technical University of Denmark (DTU)}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
}

\section{Introduction}
\frame{
\frametitle{Random}
\lipsum[1]
}

\section{Project Description}
\frame{
\frametitle{Random}
\lipsum[2]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also added `\pretocmd{\beamer@subsectionintoc}
  {\vskip0.5\itemsep}{}{}` for subsections (which, I guess, are not using `\vfill` inbetween). Is this the correct way to do it? And yes, I only need to skip `0.5\itemsep` to get the impression that subsections are grouped with the section.

Comment: @remus Yes, you're right; in the case of subsections no `\vfill` is added and your addition will give you some little extra spacing (you could have patched `\beamer@subsection` to add there the space to the ToC, but you're approach will give the desired extra spacing).

Comment: This works for the TOC at the beginning of the presentation, but it doesn't appear to have any effect on the TOC that is repeated at the beginning of sections with \AtBeginSection etc. Is there a way of making this consistent?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to patch `\tableofcontents` such that its contents are embedded inside a `minipage`:

```
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{minipage}}{}{}
```

The `MWE` then becomes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\title{Whatever Title Works}
\author{Remus M. Prunescu$^1$}
\institute{\tiny$^{1}$ Automation and Control Group, Department of Electrical Engineering, Technical University of Denmark (DTU)}

\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{minipage}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\frame{
    \maketitle
}


\frame{
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
}

\section{Introduction}
\frame{
    \frametitle{Random}
    \lipsum[1]
}

\section{Project Description}
\frame{
    \frametitle{Random}
    \lipsum[2]
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following work-around for your first frame and then play with the second argument of `\fontsize` to adjust the space between the lines:

```
\frame{
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \bgroup
    \vskip1\baselineskip
    \fontsize{10}{18}\selectfont
    \tableofcontents
    \vskip0pt plus 1filll
  \egroup
}
```

I've taken your initial example, no additional packages are necessary.