# Beamer options frame

Tags: beamer

I'd like to have normals spaces in a specific frame. Or, i've got some huge and hugly spaces. Here is a picture.

[image]

I've tried [t, allowframebreaks=.70] without succes. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=.70]
\frametitle{Plan}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}    
\section{a}
\begin{frame} aaa \end{frame}
\section{b}
\begin{frame} bbb \end{frame}
\section{c}
\begin{frame} ccc \end{frame}
\section{d}
\begin{frame} ddd \end{frame}
\section{e}
\begin{frame} eee \end{frame}
\section{f}
\begin{frame} fff \end{frame}
\section{g}
\begin{frame} ggg \end{frame}
\section{h}
\begin{frame} hhh \end{frame}
\section{i}
\begin{frame} iii \end{frame}
\section{j}
\begin{frame} jjj \end{frame}
\section{k}
\begin{frame} kkk \end{frame}
\section{l}
\begin{frame} lll \end{frame}
\section{m}
\begin{frame} mmm \end{frame}
\section{n}
\begin{frame} nnn \end{frame}
\section{o}
\begin{frame} ooo \end{frame}
\section{p}
\begin{frame} ppp \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks=.70]` works fine - however the difference in output is not very large compared to a centred frame, as the toc has lots of stretchable space between the entries.

Comment: it works for me (as expected, see @samcarter comment). i test with recent `beamer` package (version 3.49.).

Comment: hello sorry my question is maybe wrong  I will give a picture. Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your frame is perfectly top aligned - however beamer puts a `\vfill` between each section entry which causes the space between the entries to stretch so the whole page is filled.

To disable it you can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170438/36296

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{} 

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}
  {\vfill}
  {\vskip\itemsep}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Plan}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}    
\section{a}
\begin{frame} aaa \end{frame}
\section{b}
\begin{frame} bbb \end{frame}
\section{c}
\begin{frame} ccc \end{frame}
\section{d}
\begin{frame} ddd \end{frame}
\section{e}
\begin{frame} eee \end{frame}
\section{f}
\begin{frame} fff \end{frame}
\section{g}
\begin{frame} ggg \end{frame}
\section{h}
\begin{frame} hhh \end{frame}
\section{i}
\begin{frame} iii \end{frame}
\section{j}
\begin{frame} jjj \end{frame}
\section{k}
\begin{frame} kkk \end{frame}
\section{l}
\begin{frame} lll \end{frame}
\section{m}
\begin{frame} mmm \end{frame}
\section{n}
\begin{frame} nnn \end{frame}
\section{o}
\begin{frame} ooo \end{frame}
\section{p}
\begin{frame} ppp \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly in my beamers. Thanks again for this great help. Best regards,