# Style beamer table of contents like itemize

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, itemize

I would like to make `\tableofcontents` look like `\itemize`, with the same indentation, unnumbered circle radius, circle and text color, but keeping the link capability.

Is there a beamer option or I need specific package? What are beamer default presets?

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Overview}
 \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black}
 \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}{First content frame}
 \itemize
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Other item
  \item Other item
  \item Other item
  \item Other item
  \item Other item
  \item Other item
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}
\section{Other section}
\section{Other section}
\section{Other section}
\section{Other section}

\begin{frame}{Second content frame}
 \itemize
  \item Other item
  \item Other item
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table of content vs itemize]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on :

- [Separation space between tableofcontents items in beamer, answer by Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170438/141947) for the vertical distance between ToC entries
- A redefinition of a `beamer` template from the `beamer` sources
- Adding a `\quad` before `$\bullet$` to improve the horizontal spacing

```latex
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    % Patch vertical separation between sections in toc
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}
      {\vfill}
      {\vskip\itemsep}
      {}
      {}
    \makeatother  

    % Define a new style of section in toc to look like itemize
    \defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{sectionasitem}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
    \raise1.25pt\hbox{\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\quad$\bullet$}
    {\usebeamercolor*[fg]{normal text}\inserttocsection}%
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sectionasitem]

    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]


    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Overview}
     \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{First section}

    \begin{frame}{First content frame}
     \itemize
      \item First item
      \item Second item
      \item Other item
      \item Other item
      \item Other item
      \item Other item
      \item Other item
      \item Other item
    \end{frame}

    \section{Second section}
    \section{Other section}
    \section{Other section}
    \section{Other section}
    \section{Other section}

    \begin{frame}{Second content frame}
     \itemize
      \item Other item
      \item Other item
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about subsection?

Comment: @Marcel At first sight I would say replacing all `section in toc` references with `subsection in toc` should be enough

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Maybe I missed one

Comment: @Marcel Well you can ask a new question and link this one. This will allow us to see what you tried and start from there